Identify the hollow sphere without making a sound!
Recently I came across this problem,

Can we use the principle of floating and sinking here?
Both the spheres have the same mass.
So,
$\rho\cdot V=\text{constant}$
$\implies \rho \propto \frac{1}{V}$
Both the hollow and solid sphere occupy the same space,but their volumes are different,right?
When we say $\rho=\frac{m}{V}$,by $V$,we mean the volume of the object.
As $V_{\text{hollow}} < V_{\text{solid}}$,
${\rho}_ {\text{hollow}} > {\rho}_ {\text{solid}}$
Again,
$\% \text{ submerged}=\frac{{\rho}_{\text{object}}}{{\rho}_{\text{liquid}}}\cdot 100\%$
So, if we drop both the spheres in a liquid, the one that will displace more liquid will be our hollow sphere. (If none of them sink fully.)
Is my thinking correct? And what about some other ways to identify the hollow sphere? (Without making a sound,of course.)

The spheres have the same mass and the same volume, so will both sink in the same fluid. The spheres must have the same volume because they have the same radii. They're the same size.

In the context of buoyancy, the volume is the total volume enclosed by the object, including air inside of it. That’s why ballast tanks work - by filling up a large tank with air instead of water, the (decreasing) mass divided by the (constant) enclosed volume goes down, decreasing the overall density of the tank and allowing it to float/remain level/sink on command.

@ChayPaterson So you're saying their densities are equal?

@ChayPaterson they won’t necessarily sink. Only if their density is greater than that of the fluid

The densities of the materials might differ -- the material of the hollow sphere's shell must have a higher density than the material of the solid one. But the density of specific materials isn't relevant to buoyancy, only the average density: the total mass and the total volume enclosed. Ships are made of metals, which are much denser than water, and solid bars of metal will sink. But ships float because their average density is lower than water. The two spheres have the same average density, so will sink or float together as @Bob-d correctly says.

Since both spheres have the same mass and volume their average density will be the same even though the mass of the hollow sphere is concentrated away from the center. Since the degree to which they will float depends only on their average density compared to the density of the fluid they are placed in, and if that average density is less then that of the fluid, the percentage of each that is submerged will be the same.
On the other hand, since the mass of the hollow sphere will be concentrated away from the center its moment of inertia (resistance to angular acceleration) will be greater than the solid sphere. That means the hollow sphere will roll slower down an incline than the solid sphere.
Hope this helps.

Why the same volume?The volume of the solid sphere is 4/3pir³ and that of the hollow sphere should be 4/3pi(r_out³-r_in³),right?

@Interested111 The volume that's relevant for the buoyancy force is just $\tfrac 4 3\pi r_{out}^3$. It's the volume of the water that is displaced, not necessarily the volume of the metal. When Bob says they have the same volume, this volume is meant.

"Since both spheres have the same mass and volume,their average density will be the same"-I think this obviously indicates he's talking about the spheres.

@Interested111 the problem states they have the same radiu, doesn’t it? Same radii same total volume

@Interested111 total volume includes the volume of the air of the hollow sphere

@Interested111 and it doesn’t say inner or outer radius of the hollow sphere. So we must assume it is the same outer radius for both

@BobD Thanks.I forgot about the air part.

@BobD but what if the hollow part was vacuum?

@Interested111 Then as far as buoyancy is concerned you would not include the density of the air in determining the  average density of the hollow sphere, making it very slightly less. Similarly, you would not include the mass of the air in determining the moment of inertia , making the moment of inertia very slightly greater.

I don't understand how you correlated buoyancy and the density of the object.When the hollow part is vacuum,the density of the hollow sphere increases than the density of the solid sphere.So it displaces more liquid if it floats,and the buoyancy becomes larger.How would the buoyancy become slightly lesser?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

If you put them at the top of a ramp and release them from rest, the solid sphere will accelerate down the ramp faster than the hollow sphere.
Also, I don't think your logic is correct about fluid displacement.  Assuming they both sink, displaced fluid volume will be the same.   Technically the hollow sphere also has a little bit of air mass inside it (or is it vacuum?), but that would be very hard to see on a lab scale or on any practical test.  Maybe weighing underwater would show a difference though.

This is probably the correct answer but I can’t help but think that they’d make sound as they roll down the ramp… maybe we’re sorcerers and can produce perfect frictionless ramps in a vacuum at will.

Ha ha.  We don't need a frictionless ramp or pure vacuum -- just need conditions to be equal for both.

What if none of them sink fully?The hollow one will displace more liquid,right?

Initially I thought yes but now I don't think so.  The volume of the sphere below the water line multiplied by the density of the water will equal the mass of the sphere.  None of the above changes between spheres.  Whether there is air or vacuum in the hollow sphere might make a tiny little difference though.  Let's see if anyone else answers.

The volume of the sphere below the water line multiplied by the density of water will be equal to the mass of the displaced water.

If the spheres are floating, the mass of displaced water is equal to the mass of the sphere.

Both float and sink the same way. ( same mass, volume)
But in pendulum oscillations ( not possible without some hand manipulation)
$$ mL^2 \ddot \theta + mgL \sin \theta=0 $$
the hollow sphere has more moment of inertia, so less frequency of oscillation.
